# Need to understand Instance level relationship

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-relationships

I need to understand Instance level relationship in UML.
I have read several documents regarding this but not getting satisfied. I am still confused in aggregation,composition etc.

I know that some of you may feel that this is not the correct place to asking this type of question, but I couldn't think of better place then this.

Please help me here.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: Please provide some pointers for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you can't get grasp of it in higher level, you could see how the relationship is implemented in an individual language? Not sure if it suits your learning style but it certainly helped me to look at UML from more 'concrete' perspective.
Try this (questions 5-8): http://java-questions.com/oops_interview_questions.html